# Get Mosek's Certificate of Infeasibility (via Cvxpy)

Tags: cvxpy, mosek

We are formulating a optimization problem in Cvxpy and using Mosek solver.

Our problem happens to be infeasible.

Debugging of which, we require these two information from Mosek:

1. [Infeasibility Report](https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/capi/debugging-infeas.html#:%7E:text=MOSEK%20PRIMAL%20INFEASIBILITY%20REPORT): We are able to generate this perfectly.
2. [Certificate of Infeasibility](https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/pythonapi/prob-def-linear.html#primal-infeasible-problems): We are unable to get this.

Is there a way to also get the `certificate of infeasibility`, when using Mosek with Cvxpy?

Comment: cvxpy does not provide this.

Comment: Cvxpy seems to be lacking a lot of important Mosek feature, Do you have a recommendation of a high-level modelling framework, which could possibly encompass all these important features?

Comment: Note a lot of advanced stuff becomes easier if you work directly with a conic formulation. So you should switch a framework that works directly with cones and not directly with nonlinear functions that is translated to a conic formulation. We think Mosek Fusion is the best solution for that.